# Переключение кнопкой видимости jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть `div` и изначально в css он имеет параметр `display: none`. Также у нас есть ОДНА кнопка по нажатию которой div должен показаться и при повторном нажатии скрыться. Для анимированного "появления" div я использую `.fadeIn()`, а для скрытия `.fadeOut()`. Как реализовать сначала появление, а потом и, при повторном нажатии, скрыть этот div?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .block{
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            background: red;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <button class="js-show-block-btn">show/hide block</button>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(()=>{
            $( document ).on( "click",".js-show-block-btn", (ev)=>{
                let block = $(".block")
                if(block.css('display') === 'none'){
                    block.fadeIn()
                } else {
                    block.fadeOut()
                }
            } )
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```